# UITableView cell gets cut off in edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

Basically I have a table view with an array of files from a documents folder. So far I have managed to adjust the height of the cell depending on how big the text label is as so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    float height = 30;// y value of dataLabel
    CGRect labelRect = [[directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                        boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width-15, 0)
                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]}
                        context:nil];

    height=height+labelRect.size.height+30;
    return height;
}
```

If the cell.textLabel starts off as 1 line or 2 lines it's fine and shows accordingly. However, when I tap the edit button in my nav bar to bring up edit mode, if the cell.textLabel was once 1 line and drops to 2 lines because of the shrinking space, the cell won't adjust and it gets clipped by the cell border.

How an I prevent this from happening?

UPDATED with images:

[image: Before]
[image: After edit mode]

With being called:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boundingRectWithSize:` value is meant to be the **maximum size** the label can potentially be. Currently you are setting this to your desired width ok, but with a *zero* height! This may be the issue.

Please replace this `0` with `CGFLOAT_MAX`, like so

```
CGRect labelRect = [[directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                    boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width-15, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                    options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]}
                    context:nil];
```

In addition to this, make sure you have your **constraints** **configured** properly, in that each side distance constant to the *top*, l*eft, right* and *bottom* corresponding objects are pinned. (*and any other objects in the cell constrained properly*), so that when the cell height is adjusted larger, your `UILabel` holding the text stretches according to these values so you see all the text

I hope this helps

Comment: OP updated with corresponding images. I'm doing this all programmatically, so I'm not sure about constraints being set. What you suggested had no effect.

Comment: @ChrisOSX I'm wondering if setting the width of the cell to the frame of the tableview may be the cause, as it may change to allow the edit UI to appear. If you fix the width to match the screen width say, then would the edit UI pushing the whole cell to the right be a better option?

Comment: While this did work for me for the most part, mainly if it predicts that the line CAN go to 2 lines, it will auto space it, instead of the size adjustment animation. So I decided to just go on the path and setting the title to just a single line and using, NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle. Good enough for me :)

Answer (score 2):

If we want the cell content to move to right when editing in the selection mode this code in UITableViewCell subclass works fine for me provided we are using cells with dynamic height:

```
 class UITableViewCellSubclass {
        var contentViewSubviewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutContraint?

        public override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
                super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
                initializeViews()
            }

        private func initializeViews() {
            contentViewSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(contentViewSubview)
            contentViewSubviewTrailingConstraint = contentViewSubview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                contentViewSubview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
                contentViewSubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
                contentViewSubviewTrailingConstraint ?? stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
                contentViewSubview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            ])
        }

        override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
            if editing {
                contentViewSubviewTrailingConstraint?.constant = contentView.frame.origin.x
            } else {
                contentViewSubviewTrailingConstraint?.constant = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

If we want the whole content to be visible on edit mode and table view cell to adjust the height, below code in viewController works fine (with dynamic height cells and all the constraints (top , bottom, left, right) are applied correctly)

```
 override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: Especially the last paragraph was helpful. Thanks.